# Populating Gridview and Listview from List created from databaseHelper

Tags: android, gridview

I find some tutorials, to create databaseHelper class, which help me to fetch data from database, the data was fetch using List, but somehow i dont know how to populate that list into ArrayList for my gridview and list view, when i try, it says List cannot converted into ArrayList. How can i do that? here my code snippet

databaseHelper.java

```
public List<Seat> getAllSeats() {
        List<Seat> seats = new ArrayList<Seat>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_SEATS + "WHERE status=0";

        Log.e(LOG, selectQuery);

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Seat seat = new Seat();
                seat.set_id(c.getInt((c.getColumnIndex("id"))));
                seat.set_table_no(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("table_no")));

                // adding to list
                seats.add(seat);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        return seats;
    }
```

index.java

```
/* LIST SEAT */
        final ArrayList<Seat> list_seat = db.getAllSeats();
        final GridView gridview_seat = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridviewSeat);
        gridview_seat.setAdapter(new SeatListAdapter(this, list_seat));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just convert your list data into array list with following code...

```
List<Seat> list = db.getAllSeats();
ArrayList<Seat> list_seat = new ArrayList<Seat>(list.size());
list_seat .addAll(list);
```

Comment: for the third line: arrayList.addAll(list);, shouldnt it list_seat instead? i update to list_seat and its works! Thanks!